# Phase Diagram Vertical Lines

Tags: physical-chemistry, eutectic, phase-diagram

We had to create a phase diagram of H2O and NaCl. My professor mentioned that the vertical line I’ve encircled is at the weight % of 61.9. I was just wondering if this is proven through experiment or is there a way to solve this? [image]

Comment: Define ‘solve’? Phase diagrams were originally determined experimentally. Now, while their are various computational techniques most of them rely on experimentally determined points to make the computations ‘right’.

Comment: This was also what I was thinking--I was just unsure if it's possible to solve it without experimental data. Thanks so much for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The vertical line marked by you is a *phase boundary*.

At temperatures below $\pu{0.1 ^\circ{}C}$, anything to the right of this boundary is a mixture of variable composition consisting of solid sodium chloride, $\ce{NaCl}$, and sodium chloride dihydrate ([hydrohalite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrohalite)). The two compounds coexist. The crystal structure of the later regularly contains molecules of water and is considerably less dense ($\pu{1.656 g/cm^3}$), than halite ($\pu{2.17 g/cm^3}$ [[ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride)]).

[image]

(structure model of hydrohalite, $\ce{NaCl * 2 H2O}$, as entry [COD 4513223](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/4513223.html), based on Bode *et al.* Oxygen represented by red, hydrogen: white, sodium: purple, and chloride: green spheres.)

Left to this line, there is a liquid state of varying composition: solid $\ce{NaCl * 2 H2O}$ in a liquid aqueous solution of sodium chloride.

Bode, A. A. C.; Pulles, P. G. M.; Lutz, M.; Poulisse, W. J. M.; Jiang, S.; Meijer, J. A. M.; Van Enckevort, W. J. P.; Vlieg, E. Sodium Chloride Dihydrate Crystals: Morphology, Nucleation, Growth, and Inhibition. *Cryst. Growth  Des.* **2015**, *15*, 3166–3174. https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.cgd.5b00061.